# Prevent visual studio creating browse info (.ncb) files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to prevent VS2008 creating browse info file files for C++ projects.
I rarely use the class browser and it isn't worth the time it takes to recreate it after every build, especially since it runs even if the build failed.

EDIT - it's also needed for go to declaration/definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a registry key for this as well: `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Languages\Language Services\C/C++]`

Intellisense ON

```
"IntellisenseOptions"=dword:00000000
```

Intellisense OFF

```
"IntellisenseOptions"=dword:00000007
```

Intellisense ON - NO Background UPDATE

```
"IntellisenseOptions"=dword:00000005
```

More flags are available and you can [Control Intellisense through Macros](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2007/11/19/controlling-intellisense-through-macros.aspx) as well.

```
ISENSE_NORMAL = 0       'normal (Intellisense On)
ISENSE_NOBG = &H1       'no bg parsing (Intellisense Updating Off - although NCB file will be opened r/w and repersisted at shutdown)
ISENSE_NOQUERY = &H2    'no queries (don't run any ISense queries)
ISENSE_NCBRO = &H4      'no saving of NCB (must be set before opening NCB, doesn't affect updating or queries, just persisting of NCB)
ISENSE_OFF = &H7
```

Answer (score 5):

In the project properties, you will find the browse information under:

Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Browse Information

Just tell it not to generate browse information.  All it is used for is quickly browsing between code components (like using 'Go to Definition') and so forth.  I personally like being able to quickly jump between the components, but if it is adding unnecessary time to your compile don't worry about turning it off.

Comment: Doesn't this control the BSC file ?  I don't think it's used for the NCB file.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a folder with the same name of the ncb file (you'll have to delete the file, of course). I used this trick in the past to prevent intellisense from locking VS2005. You'll lose intellisense, though.

Comment: Creating a read only 0 byte file also works (at least in VS2005)

Comment: It also displays a warning dialog every time you open the project that warns that Intellisense is not available for the project.